# Can I retrieve user's PAC file (Proxy Auto Config)?

Tags: .net, proxy, pac

Is it possible?

Currently I'm trying per domain to get what proxy the system designates to it, this way:

```
Uri website = new Uri("http://google.com");
System.Net.IWebProxy defaultproxy = System.Net.WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
Uri proxy = defaultproxy.GetProxy(website);
```

This way I know what proxy the system gives me to google.com. 
But is it possible to get the whole pac file (javascript)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure if it's best practice, but what I've managed so far is reading it using `regedit`. The relevant *key* is located here:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\AutoConfigURL`

Hope it helps someone.